# How to use matrix language to describe the solution process?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-diophantine-equations

I see that the linear equations $\left\{\begin{array}{l}
2 x+y-t=-2 \\
3 y+z+2 t=3
\end{array}\right.$ can be solved in the following way:

[image]

I have uploaded a picture to give the details of the algorithm for the mathematical solution. It is obvious that this method is quite different from the calculation method commonly used in linear algebra textbooks. I want to explain the principle of this algorithm clearly, but I don't even understand the principle at present.

*The above similar contents are from page 206 of [this textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821840908):*

[image]

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
2 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 2 \\
0 & 3 & 1 & 2 & -3 \\
\hline 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right) \rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
3 & -6 & 1 & 5 & -3 \\
\hline 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -9 \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -2 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 6 & -5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -2 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 6 & -5 & -9 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

Then we can get the following relationship:

$$\left(\begin{array}{l}
x \\
y \\
z \\
t
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
-2 \\
9 \\
0
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 \\
6 & -5 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}
c_{1} \\
c_{2}
\end{array}\right)$$

But I want to use matrix language to describe and prove the solution process:

$$\begin{array}{c}
A.X = B\\
M.A.X = M.B\\
M.A.X.N = M.B.N\\
\text{If }M.B.N = 0\\
\text{then }M.A.X.N = 0\\
\end{array}$$

How can I simply describe and prove the solution process?

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for your comments. I have added some source information.

Comment: Could you explain each of the steps?

Comment: @Servaes The operation is to transform the composite matrix into a special ladder-type by some elementary row or column transformations. But I do not understand the specific principle of the algorithm, so I put forward this problem, hoping to explain the principle of the algorithm with the help of concise matrix language.

Comment: My version of the book has no such algorithm on page 206. Could you include a copy of the relevant passage?

Comment: @Servaes I have uploaded the relevant screenshots, and I applied this method to an example.

Comment: Have you understood the case $m=1$ treated in the two pages before?

Comment: Also, what is the point of this algorithm, and why do you want to understand it? There are far simpler, more direct and more efficient methods, such as Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @Servaes I probably know that the final general solution represents all possible integer solutions, but the principle is not clear. I will study it carefully for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your approach in the picture for to solve this problem. However, this problem in the matricix language is easy. Note that  if $$(S.E.L): \left\{\begin{aligned} 2x+y+0z-t=-2 \\ 0x+3y+z+2t=3 \end{aligned} \right.$$
so, we can write the S.E.L in the form $$AX=B \quad \text{and} \quad (A|B)$$
Taking the coefficients of the system of linear equations, we construct the matrix $A$, this's $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
and taking the unknows of the S.E.L, we have $$X=\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ t \end{pmatrix}$$
and finally, $$B=\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore, you have $$\left\{\begin{aligned} 2x+y+0z-t=-2 \\ 0x+3y+z+2t=3 \end{aligned} \right. \iff \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}}_{A}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ t \end{pmatrix}}_{X}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}}_{B}$$
Now, you can use  [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Example_of_the_algorithm) here $$(A|B) \iff \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 & -1 & | & -2 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 & 2 & | & 3\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Your answer is great, but I want to know how this algorithm works.